# Open failed: EACCES (Permission denied) Exception from Image Picker

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, uri, android-image, imagepicker

In my jetpack compose project, I have an image picker, and when I pick an image from the `recents` list and do a custom image compression operation, it works fine, but if the image is picked from the gallery or files app, the image compression code throws an error stating that it couldn't find the file even though the file exists in that location. What could be the issue?

**Exception message**

```
/storage/3134-6133/Pictures/Fruits/Bananas Organic.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

**Error message**

```
E/MediaProvider: Couldn't find file: /storage/3134-6133/Pictures/Fruits/Bananas Organic.jpg
```

```
override fun compressItemImage(context: Context, sharedViewModel: SharedViewModel) {
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        try {
            val compressedImageUri = context.compressImage(
                _addItemScreenState.value.editedItemImageUri?.toUri()!!,
                "item_images",
                "item_image_compressed"
            )
            setStateValue(ITEM_IMAGE_URI_STR, compressedImageUri)

            val thumbnailUri = context.createImageThumbnail(
                _addItemScreenState.value.editedItemImageUri?.toUri()!!,
                "thumbnails/item_thumbnails",
                "item_image_thumbnail"
            )
            setStateValue(ITEM_THUMBNAIL_URI_STR, thumbnailUri)

            if (sharedViewModel.isEdit.value) {
                updateShoppingListItemToDb()
            } else {
                addShoppingListItemToDb()
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            setStateValue(
                IS_NAVIGATE_TO_LIST_SCREEN_STR,
                false
            )
        }
    }
}
```

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
suspend fun Context.compressImage(imageUri: Uri, destFolder: String, filePrefix: String): Uri {
    var newUri: Uri = Uri.EMPTY
    try {
        val originalFile: File = UriUtils.uri2File(imageUri)
        val timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis()
        val directory =
            File(this.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), destFolder)
        if (!directory.exists()) directory.mkdirs()

        val newFile = File(
            directory.absolutePath,"${filePrefix}_${timestamp}" + ".jpg"
        )

        newFile.createNewFile()

        Compressor.compress(this, originalFile) {
            default(format = Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG)
            destination(newFile)
        }

        newUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
            this,
            applicationContext.packageName + ".fileprovider",
            newFile
        )
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to process your image.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

    return newUri
}
```

**file_paths.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-files-path
        name="my_images"
        path="Android/data/<app-package>/files/Pictures"/>
    <external-files-path
        name="my_debug_images"
        path="/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<app-package>/files/Pictures/"/>
    <external-files-path
        name="root_images"
        path="/"/>
    <external-files-path
        name="extfiles"
        path="."/>
    <external-path name="photos" path="." />

</paths>
```

Comment: `UriUtils.uri2File(imageUri)` -- this is likely the source of your difficulty. A `Uri` is not a file. Since image files are already compressed, it is unclear what the purpose of `compressImage()` is. But, if you insist on having it, use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content identified by the `Uri`, then "compress" that.

Comment: I'm compressing it because I'm trying to reduce the memory size of the images, especially if it's been taken from the camera which can be large. But, the compressimage function comes from an external library and it requires `File` references, not a `Uri`, hence the need to use the `uri2File` third party utility. I'll try to use `ContentResolver` as you suggested.

Comment: "I'm compressing it because I'm trying to reduce the memory size of the images" -- [JPEG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG) files from cameras are already compressed. My guess is that you are trying to reduce the resolution of the image. If so, you can do that [using `BitmapFactory.decodeStream()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory#decodeStream(java.io.InputStream,%20android.graphics.Rect,%20android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options)).

Comment: I demonstrate using `BitmapFactory` to reduce image resolution in [this older sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Bitmaps/InSampleSize), though in that case I am working with assets rather than with an `InputStream` from a `Uri`, as in your case. However, the principle still holds. I cover `BitmapFactory` in the "Bitmap Sizing" section of the "Issues with Application Heap" chapter of [this older free book of mine](https://commonsware.com/Android/), using the aforementioned project as a sample.

Comment: Once you have the `Bitmap` at the desired resolution, you can write it out to your destination file by calling `compress()` on the `Bitmap`.

Comment: I'm not trying to reduce the resolution. When I take a picture with the camera, the resulting image file size is about 2 or 3 MB, I want to compress such images to reduce the file size before storing it in the app's internal storage. I think the resolution does go down with compression a little but that's not my original intention. And with the current compression implementation, the image file size actually goes down to about 100KB.

Comment: I'm getting the following error with the issue originally described. What could be wrong with the code?: `open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)`. I updated the original question.

Comment: You do not have read access to the filesystem at arbitrary locations on removable storage. Use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content identified by the `Uri`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, I needed to ask for the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission also. My current code only asked for `ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION` permission. Everything is working now.